# Is it possible to fit a linear model of y in log scale but with offset in the original scale?

Tags: regression, data-transformation, lognormal-distribution, offset

Let's start with simple linear regression with log transformation of the response variable y:

$$ \log(y_i) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + e_i$$

(btw, how is this model called? log-linear regression or lognormal regression?)

I'm trying to model a variable $y$ that has a log-decay with $x$, say time. But at a few time points (e.g. $x^0$), there are external sources ($c_0$) contribute to $y$ directly. Then after this point, $y$ follows a log-decay with $x$ again but start with a jump in the original scale.

$$ y_i = e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + e_i},  x_i \leq x^0 $$

$$ y_i = (e^{\beta_0 + \beta_1 x^0+ e_i} + c_0)e^{\beta_1(x_i - x^0)},  x_i > x^0 $$

This is the simplest case with only one change point. Is it possible to fit this kind of model? Does it make sense?

Comment: Are you sure this is an appropriate model?  It implies that every jump persists forever: the asymptotic value of $y$ is the sum of all the jumps over all time, which is not necessarily zero.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @whuber! That is what I want the jumps to do (persists forever, then decay from the new value). Do you think this is an appropriate model?

Comment: You should be able to fit it on Maximum Likelihood. What is the distribution of your $e_i$? Assuming these are iid, all you should need to do is to derive the implied distribution for $y_i$ and optimize your params for maximum likelihood. Might be a good idea to guess some param values, generate few $e_i$  and see what it implies for $y_i$.